# AJAX and auto-refreshing

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

im trying to get a bit of html to refresh every 1 second with AJAX, I made this code my self with bits from different websites that I found. Im trying to understand how it all works.

I want to be able to refresh the page without reloading it in the browser and I want the JS function AJAXdisplay(); to run every one second with the variables I send to AJAXreturn(); when I call it.

When I call  AJAXreturn(); I want it to run AJAXdisplay(); once to print out the html from my php file, on my body if the index file I want somthing like this

```
 <body onClick=:AJAXdisplay(same variables as used when the page was made);">             

</body>
```

here is my code:

```
function getHTTPObject(){
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
    return null;
}
}   

function AJAXsend(url) {
httpObject = getHTTPObject();
if (httpObject != null) {
    httpObject.open("POST",url);
    httpObject.send(null);
}
}

function AJAXreturn(url,pageName){
httpObject = getHTTPObject();
if (httpObject != null) {
    if (navigator.appName != "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        history.replaceState("", "", "index.php?page=" + pageName)
    }
    httpObject.open("POST",url);
    httpObject.send(null);
    AJAXdisplay(httpObject,url,pageName);
}
}

function AJAXdisplay(httpObjectIn,urlIn, pageNameIn){
httpObjectIn.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(httpObjectIn.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById('outputHTML').innerHTML = httpObjectIn.responseText;
        AJAXdisplay('function(httpObjectIn,urlIn,pageNameIn)',1000);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: russell.selfip.net is where it is now

Comment: maybe I must put all of this into one function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make javascript refresh, you should use the `setInterval();` function. Here's what your looking for:

```
var timer = setInterval ("AJAXdisplay(variable);", 1000);
```

And if you ever need to stop the refresh you use:

```
clearInterval (timer);
```